# waiting for the image to be downloaded before incrementing

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a for loop that will download image on a server and here is what it looks

```
for (int i = 0; i < sync_data.length(); i++) {
    String main_link = "LINK" + folder + "/" + file_name;
    FilePathname = sdCardDirectory + "/" + file_name;
    DownloadFilesname(FilePathname, main_link);

    index++;
    p = (float) index / (float) sync_data.length();
    p = p * (float) 100;

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            publishProgress((int) p);
        }
    });
}
```

/* Function Image Download */

```
 public void DownloadFilesname(String filanme, String Urlname) {
        try {
            URL u = new URL(Urlname);
            InputStream is = u.openStream();

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filanme));
            while ((length = dis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "malformed url error", mue);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "io error", ioe);
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "security error", se);
        }
    }
```

my problem is the `publishProgress` already updated even the image is not yet downloaded. This will cause the asynctask to be done but the image is still downloading..

How can I make that the image must be downloaded before increment?

Comment: Please post code for `DownloadFilesname`

Comment: @lionscribe done. sorry i forgot

Comment: Abt the comment where you don't see the files. Not sure if this will make the difference but you are not closing the files after writting them. Anyway yo should be closing the files so add: fos.flush() and fos.close() after the write loop.

Comment: @Juan on what part should i add that?

Comment: After: while ((length = dis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

Comment: @Juan thanks for it but it has nothing to do with my question

Comment: Sorry, but as files get written through buffers, and buffers are flushed when you close the stream (which wasn't what you were doing), I thought it might had to do with your question.

Comment: @Juan thanks for the help. I hope you can help on my main prob. but still TY

Answer (score 0):

You only have to call "publishProgress()" in your "doInBackground()" and then implement/override

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    ...
}
```

When you call "publishProgress()" the "onProgressUpdate()" event is called in the Ui/MainThread (it means you can use all the UI components inside it)

Comment: actually the part of the code i posted is inside `doInBackground` and I update the `publishProgress` after download. It does increment but after the loading is done i checked on the folder and it still downloading the images